# How to convert oracle timestamp to zulu format

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle

When I'm reading a timestamp from oracle database and I'll try to convert it to utc format I'm getting this error 
**Conversion from string "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ" to type 'Integer' is not valid.**

I am getting the data like this : 
 `2016-05-05T11:53:33+01:00`
 and I'll do

```
dr("COLUMNAME").ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to use DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I managed to do the conversion. The solution is

```
Dim dataCreated As Date = DateTime.Parse(dr("columnName")) 
dataCreated.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")
```